# USB GNSS device never gets attached?

Tags: drivers, usb, serial-port

I insert my GNSS device via USB in hopes of getting a device path to read serially from it:
I do this using my raspberry Pi 4 that I intend to use as a rtk ntrip caster.

lusb gives:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1546:01a9 U-Blox AG u-blox GNSS receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg gives:

```
[ 175.728623] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 175.833153] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a9, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 175.833183] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 175.833196] usb 1-1.1: Product: u-blox GNSS receiver
[ 175.833206] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com
[ 414.271561] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 417.902463] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 418.006723] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1546, idProduct=01a9, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 418.006752] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 418.006764] usb 1-1.3: Product: u-blox GNSS receiver
[ 418.006775] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com
```

After plugging it in twice in different ports. I never seem to get a attach point like /dev/ttyS0 such that I can use the port.
What is going on here? It is supposed to be just a serial communication port to my knowledge, but perhaps not?.

Comment: Have you installed the `gpsd` package? That has some additional `udev` that should take care of the connection validation: `sudo apt install gpsd`

Comment: Thanks for the response, just tried it, but I don't seem to get any more success in the dmesg prompt with that even after restart. Neither do I find any new /dev/ devices.